# Magento Toggle Inc/Ex Tax

Tags: magento, toggle, taxonomy

I have seen on some magento sites a button in the menu bar which switches all of the sites prices from Inc VAT to Ex VAT or the other way around. I've been searching to find the best way of achieving this for magento but I am yet to be successful!

If somebody could give me a solution to this then I'd be highly thankful!